# JQuery-Need help understanding (i, el)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am having trouble understanding this piece of code.

```
var win = $(window);
var allMods = $(".module");

// Already visible modules
allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible"); 
  } 
});

win.scroll(function(event) {

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in"); 
    } 
  });

});
```

I understand that the bottom half of the code runs when the window is scrolled and that both allMods.each blocks are loops that iterate over all the elements with the "module" class.

There are three things I don't understand:

1. Shouldn't the .each function take in an array or object and a callback function as parameters? Here it just takes a function.
2. Why are "i" and "el" being passed in as parameters to the function. I'm guessing "el" refers to the current element being iterated over, but why did they call it "el". Could you replace all the "el"s for any other name? I have no idea what "i" is.
3. When does the block in the top half run? It is not inside the win.scroll event.

Comment: `i` is the zero-based index

Comment: `i` is index, starting at `0` and iterating through until the end of the loop. The top half of the code will execute once the script has loaded.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the .each function take in an array or object and a callback function as parameters? Here it just takes a function.

No. You are calling it as a method on a jQuery object. It is that object that it loops over. Internally `each` uses `this` to determine that.

> Why are "i" and "el" being passed in as parameters to the function. I'm guessing "el" refers to the current element being iterated over, but why did they call it "el". Could you replace all the "el"s for any other name? I have no idea what "i" is.

You can use whatever names you like for function arguments, it has no effect on what values are passed into it when it is called. Determining that is the responsibility of the calling function (i.e. the internals of `each`). The values that are passed into them are described in [the documentation for `each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
```

The first argument is the index in the jQuery object. The second argument is the element that is the value of that index.

> When does the block in the top half run? It is not inside the win.scroll event.

The same time any other code that isn't inside a function will run. When the script is loaded into the document.

Comment: Thank you! I understood everything except for why "i" is passed in. Isn't the function passed into $().each() a regular function? Why does it need an index parameter if it isn't even going to be referenced inside the function?

Comment: When the function gets called, the first argument will be the index. That is what jQuery does. If the person writing the function that gets called doesn't want to use the first argument, then they don't have to, but they can't control what the first argument is.

Comment: Do only functions that get passed into .each() need an index as the first parameter? Or does this apply to more functions? I'm new to jQuery :).

Comment: As I said in the answer. When `each` calls your function, the first argument it passes to it will be the index. You can call that argument whatever you like. What arguments will be passed to other functions depend on how those other functions are called. You and other people can write code which calls a function and passes an index as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. [`$().each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) runs on a jQuery object (collection of elements) and only takes a function as a parameter.
2. See the documentation linked above. `i` is the index (0-based) and `el` is the element itself. Yes, you can freely change the names as long as you change the references inside the function as well.
3. It runs at startup, whenever that block of code gets executed.